# The phantom "hi whatsup?"

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I happened to stumble across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285294/multiple-sounds-in-soundplayer) post that was obviously in desperate need of editing,

> [image]

But, when I went to actually edit the post, "hi whatsup?" vanished,

> [image]

I'm also not the only [one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18193981#18193981) that's experienced this. What's causing this to happen?

Comment: Similar MSE post: [Edit source differs from question view? Or are we each other's friends now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/edit-source-differs-from-question-view-or-are-we-each-others-friends-now)

Comment: Marginally related, considering that the post in question is now "on hold" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If the first line of a post starts with:

> Hi, ....

or a variant thereof it's automatically stripped out of the post. This is a relatively new thing.

The post you were editing was from 2009, so predates this change. This filter (like the checking for banned words in titles) is applied when a post is edited so the salutation will disappear as you edit.

Comment: Does this only happen with certain words at the beginning of the post? Or does this also apply to the ending?

Comment: @Sam I think it only applies to salutations at the beginning of a post. Locating where a post ends and a signature begins is a little less accurate.

Comment: Ha, that explains a couple of things..!

Comment: @BilltheLizard [I seem to have found a post with salutations in front!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220507/setting-useraget-in-php-file-get-contents) (Note: If it got edited, check the revisions)

Comment: @Unihedron I think the overall appalling grammar of that "sentence" (no punctuation at all) has probably fooled the code.

Comment: Should I carry on and edit the post? Or should I leave it for posterity's sake?

Comment: @Sam - edit it.

Comment: Is this also done for ending with "thanks!" etc ?

Comment: Related post from Jeff Atwood: [We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/193139)

Comment: But it's weird that you cannot see it even in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1285294/revisions).

Comment: Chris, is it possible that in future; after a major SO release happens, create a meta post stating a list of changes went in that release. That way people will be aware of the new changes they should see.

Comment: @Rahul: as far as I know, [there is a post about recent changes on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). But no mention of the automatic stripping out. [The post TLama has linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) is in the related questions list, though.

Comment: I just have one issue with this - everything is being done to make the whole process impersonal. While I do agree with / against overwhelming the posts with too much of it, I personally would like to see a bit of a friendly personal touch from time to time. And "suggesting" against it is ok (or even moderator editing at times) - but automatically stripping ?! I don't think so, just my thoughts ;)