# Auto Remove "Thanks in Advance"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I came across [The phantom "hi whatsup?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268236/the-phantom-hi-whatsup) in the questions feed and @ChrisF [explained how it works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268237/790387).

I was wondering if it would be okay to enhance this feature to remove the "Thanks in advance" as well.  The pattern is:

```
[post text]
[blank line]
Thanks in advance
```

I am aware of [Why is it considered rude to say 'thanks in advance'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/why-is-it-considered-rude-to-say-thanks-in-advance) and I'm not talking about the rudeness or correctness of the statement, I just believe its not appropriate in a *question*; similarly to how "Hi" does not add much.  Editing the question and removing this would likely flag as "too minor edit", so I think its good to have this part of the automatic cleanup.

There has been much discussed on this already:

- [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
- [Suggested Edits add "Thanks in Advance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97136/suggested-edits-add-thanks-in-advance)
- [Why are edits removing "Thanks in advance" sometimes rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153074/why-are-edits-removing-thanks-in-advance-sometimes-rejected)

Comment: It'd be a good way of making life just a bit more difficult for rep scoring bot-editors and their cult following of robo-reviewers ...

Comment: I've also seen a lot of answers with "hope this helps"/"good luck" at the end. Perhaps we could filter those too?

Comment: @Sam I am specifically talking about questions - the better the question, the better the answers and overall quality of the site. Such garnish like "hope this helps" in the answers is not _that_ big of an issue.

Comment: Funny thing is I have reviewed suggested edits which did nothing but add "Thanks in advance!" to the posts haha

Comment: Regarding "Thanks in advance" getting approved as suggested edit, automatically removing this is just hiding the underlying problem (robo-reviewers and trying to get around the minimum character limit). A much better solution would be to make a query for the mods that finds all suggested and approved edits that add "thanks in advance" or similar phrases, and then edit-ban and review-ban all repeated offenders. Why waste a perfect review-audit by automatically correcting it?

Comment: IMHO, much ado about nothing. Whether you agree or whether you don't -- Thanks in advance for your consideration!

Comment: Can we just *not give reputation* to suggested edits that only remove "Thanks in advance"?

Comment: You should've ended your post with "Thanks in advance".

Comment: It's absolutely nuts how much time and energy this community wastes on utterly inane "issues" such as these.

Comment: A great majority of my (more recent) edits are to remove "Thanks!" or "Thanks in advance"-type text from questions to make them cleaner. If you have the required rep, it is easy to just click edit, remove the text, and save, since you don't earn rep/have to go through the edit queue. I don't think the benefits to blocking these phrases (cleaner posts overall) outweigh the potential drawbacks (user confusion).

Comment: There is nothing inappropriate about saying "Thanks" in a question. For many it does add to a Q. Such criticism (and other things) adds to an exclusive tone of SO. Why is what the "Stack Overflow community much prefers" pre-determined? In a world where we are trying to encourage all types of people to be developers, keep in mind that such small acts can foster a hostile atmosphere, esp for newcomers. Besides, as others say it doesn't matter for the usually experienced answerers. Such site changes seem a small matter, but it's a big info ethics consideration, esp on a prominent site like SO

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm not completely opposed to this, and we do have the ability to warn (and by warn, I mean show a helpful message when certain patterns match), but we already strip out a lot of salutations behind the scenes.

Taking stuff people put in a text box out *silently* is a source of confusion. Automatically stripping some, and warning (through just-in-time help) for others is really inconsistent. I'd rather handle all 'thanks and salutations' in the same manner, dears.

Going to bring this up with a few folks. The question is, do we continue doing what we're doing and *automatically* remove it, or do we do something like this:

> Salutations and thanks aren't necessary within your question, the Stack Overflow community much prefers brevity. Just get straight to the point of your question, and show thanks by up-voting answers that you find useful.

But we don't outright *block* - I don't know. Half of me thinks this would do better at teaching the *why* behind that particular quirk, the other half thinks half the people that see it would just ignore it.

I'm not opposed to it, I just want to do it consistently, and we're now moving to a more 'just in time' sort of system as opposed to silently removing / blocking.

Thoughts welcome, I'm not putting a status on it, we're just (I think) at the point where we probably need to reevaluate it.

Comment: I think if something is automatically stripped out, a preview screen should be presented with the changes, and more help explaining them. It won't confuse users as much

Comment: _Dears_ indeed. Stack Overflow is [filled](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25235806/2982225) [with](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25234955/2982225) [dearness](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25249152/2982225)

Comment: There was a case a while ago where a user started off with "Hi..." then proceeded to explain his problem on the first line. The system automatically removed his "Hi", along with half of his question... silently, without explanation. Not a great experience. Showing the warning you propose in all cases would be much better. The same also goes for removing `@OP_Name` silently from comment replies as well.

Comment: `s/Stack Overflow/$sitename/` ;)

Comment: +1 if we also do this for "thanks in advanced". In that case, please add "BTW, **Thanks in advanced**" is bad English.

Comment: Maybe we could also add a CSS style to the offending text to show off the part that offends us, and, in case the pattern match matches the wrong text, to show off what it matched.

Comment: Could this type of feedback be included in my suggestion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: Ban people that ignore it

Answer (score 37):

Just an idea, what about rather than auto stripping it, the system doesn't let you post it until you remove it from the question.

That way the user doesn't wonder where it's gone, or get annoyed about it being removed for them, and also they then learn that including it is bad, and *hopefully* teaches them a little bit about asking better, to the point questions?

Comment: +1 I was just about to suggest the same... It may be easy to clean up. It may be easy to auto-clean-up. But it is better to make OP clean it up.

Answer (score 4):

I think that auto strip is not good feature. I suggest to add a check in where you actually write your question and if check detects something like this, system will warn and did not allow to post question until corrected.