# "Thanks in advance" - Automatically hint user

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions

**"Hi"** and **"Thanks in advance"** or **"Cheers, Martin"** are so common among beginners, it's astonishing! Taking the tour or reading how to ask questions before posting here is something very few users actually do, so they simply don't know better.

*Yes, they should take the tour, but in practice they often don't.*

This is not a duplicate of [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268468/auto-remove-thanks-in-advance), where automatic removal is suggested. I would like to **suggest** a hint instead. It's already working on titles:

[image]

These things also don't always get edited because there's just so many of them.

> And by the way
>
> ## Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just automatically delete it...don't even warn.

Comment: I don't know if automated deletion of any kind is a good idea. It could be potentially harmful in edge-cases.

Comment: We do it already with greetings, and it hasn't been a problem for years.

Comment: @bytecode77 Besides `Thanks in advance` you would also have to include: `Thanks in advantage` :) These are always the best!

Comment: I think the StackExchange staff is well capable of handling regexes :)

Comment: No regex will handle [advance thank you](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22advance+thank+you%22), [thanks in forward](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+in+forward%22), [thanks on advance](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+on+advance%22), [thx in advance](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thx+in+advance%22), [thanx in advance](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanx+in+advance%22),  [thx you](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thx+you%22), [thank you in forward](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+you+in+forward%22), and my favorite, `plz halp !`

Comment: I put so much effort into my previous comment, plz upvote it ! Thanks in advantage.

Comment: Oki doki. Plz upvote my question first!!! THX in adv@nt@ge!!! cu bro! :D

Comment: You want to block greetings specifically from Commonwealth-English-speaking users named Martin? Have you have some bad experience you need to talk about?

Comment: More seriously: I agree that warning would be better than automated deletion. For one thing, false negatives are a lot less harmful when they give spurious warnings (which the user will probably just laugh about) than when they break the sense of a question. For another, that may actually help _teach_ the user, rather than cleaning up after them so they'll just put another "Urgent!!! Please!!!" on their next question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The objections seem to come in two flavors:

1. If we can detect it, we can just delete it.
2. We can't detect it well enough, there will be too many false positives.

I think objection #2 serves as a great counter to objection #1, but not as a counter to the proposal.

Imagine that I'm asking a question, and the sample input for my MCVE is a bunch of RSVPs to invitations.

If I post the question, and my sample input is butchered by auto-deletion, I'm going to have a bad question, and get a bunch of comments like "Most of the patterns you're searching for don't appear anywhere in your input text, so why did you even expect this to work?" before I realize what happened.

If I post the question, and I get a warning pointing at my sample input that says "Phrases like 'Thanks' and 'Hello' add nothing to the question, and shouldn't be included. See Asking Good Questions", I'll just giggle about it and post my question. No harm done.

On top of that, letting a user know how he's not following the rules, instead of trying to automatically clean up after him, is the only thing that has any chance of teaching him. Sure, many people will just never learn. But for the ones who might, it won't happen unless they have something to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

These phrases should not be blocked outright.

If you do, how can I get help writing a GreaseMonkey script to automatically remove search results from users whose posts contain "(T|t)h(anks|x|anx) (i|o)n (advan(ce|tage|ced|cement)|forward)"?  (Including, of course, this very Meta question.  mwahahaha!)

For any noise phrase you can think of, there are always legitimate text-processing questions about detecting and/or filtering it.

---

That doesn't mean that they can't feed into a post quality assessment and trigger low quality post review, etc.

Also, blocking it when it appears at the very end of a question may be less problematic than when it's in the middle of the explanation.