# Show a warning window when OP add "thanks" in the question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I always see some question with *thanks*, and I also always remove them because: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Now my idea is, what about show a warning window when user added *thanks* or *any help would be...* in the question? Warning window(is this it name?) like this:

[image: example warning window]

But says something such like:

> No need say 'thanks' here, Check [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

I think this way maybe better than [just remove them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268468/auto-remove-thanks-in-advance), however more friendly. And we don't need busy on *removed thanks* and tells OP *don't need say thanks here*, etc.

Comment: I feel that thanking people for their time at the end of a post is just polite. I agree with "Hi", "Hi all" et al. is a waste of time, but I think that there is always time for thanks at the end of a post when people go out of there way help you and read your question.

Comment: @Killercam: If you were writing a letter, it would be polite. As-is, it's blatant disregard for the communities well-considered norms, be it through ignorance or contempt.

Comment: No, I disagree. It is not "contempt" of guidelines, I can't find where it is explicitly documented not to say "thanks for your time". It is a choice; I prefer to be polite to those giving up their time to help me. There is no reason this should not happen, to me it is important.

Comment: @Killercam *I can't find where it is explicitly documented not to say "thanks for your time"*... In the question which is [linked to, twice, in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)? And also [the third point here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and [the last paragraph here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? And also [the answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267387/215552), and probably another dozen other questions about this on Meta over the years...?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I think add thanks in question doesn't clear the question, sometimes I'd add a thanks comment below a great answer...However, I think(again, just **I think**) add thanks in question can only spend our time, I always need skip them and check the *real* question. Also there's some people like add thanks at middle of the question...